# Using C# and MediaInfo How to detect HDR format

Tags: c#, video, mediainfo

I'm using the [MediaInfo Nuget Wrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaInfo.Wrapper/) to analyse a bunch of files

using MediaInfo Actual on a file I can see

```
Video 
ID : 1 
Format : HEVC 
Format/Info : High Efficiency Video Coding 
Format profile : Main 10@L5.1@Main 
HDR format : Dolby Vision, Version 1.0, dvhe.05.09, BL+RPU 
Codec ID : dvhe 
Codec ID/Info : High Efficiency Video Coding with Dolby Vision
```

This is also seen with `Console.WriteLine(mw1.Inform());`

However I'm unable to get that from the code below
I've tried HDR format, HDRformat and other speling but always returns ""

Given the fact that every file will be different is there a more dynamic way of doing this rather than hard coding each property?

Code still at testing stage

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MediaInfo;
using MediaInfo.Model;

namespace GetMediaInfo
{
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string BaseFold = @"Path\To\Test\Samples";

        string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(BaseFold, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var Vid in Files)
        {

            string VidName = Path.GetFileName(Vid);
            if (VidName.EndsWith("jpg"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(VidName);

            var mw1 = new MediaInfo.MediaInfo();
            mw1.Option("ParseSpeed", "0");
            mw1.Open(Vid);
            string ToDisplay = "";
            var videostreamcount = mw1.CountGet(StreamKind.Video, 0);
            var AudioStreamcount = mw1.CountGet(StreamKind.Audio, 0);
            if (videostreamcount > 0)
            {
                    
                Console.WriteLine(mw1.Inform());
                foreach (var item in mw1.Get(StreamKind.Video,0,"*"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
                var Height = mw1.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "Height");
                var Width = mw1.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "Width");
                var VidFormat = mw1.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "Format");
                var HDRformat = mw1.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "HDR format"); // Always = ""
                var Codec = mw1.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "CodecID/Info");
                var CodecID = mw1.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "CodecID");
                Console.WriteLine("Height " + Height + ", Width " + Width + ", Codec " + Codec + ", CodecID " + CodecID + ", Format " + VidFormat + " , HDR format " + HDRformat);


                ToDisplay += "\r\n\r\nInfo_Parameters\r\n";
                ToDisplay += mw1.Option("Info_Parameters");

                //ToDisplay += "\r\n\r\nInfo_Capacities\r\n";
                //ToDisplay += mw1.Option("Info_Capacities");

                //ToDisplay += "\r\n\r\nInfo_Codecs\r\n";
                //ToDisplay += mw1.Option("Info_Codecs");
            //    Console.WriteLine(ToDisplay);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error No video streams in file");
            }

            if (AudioStreamcount > 0)
            {

                var AudioCodec = mw1.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "CodecID/Info");
                var AudioCodecID = mw1.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "CodecID");
                var AudioFormat = mw1.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "Format");

                Console.WriteLine("AudioCodec: {0}, AudioCodecID: {1}, AudioFormat {2}", AudioCodec, AudioCodecID, AudioFormat);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error No Audio streams in file");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried HDR format, HDRformat and other speling but always returns ""

```
HDR_Format
```

Tip: for knowing the keys to use, use MediaInfo command line with " --Language=raw" or graphical interface with XML output.

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo

Comment: Thank You @Jérôme Martinez that worked. I knew it had to be something simple XML output tip will be handy going forward